# При попытке работать с массивом выдается ошибка Segmentation fault. Необходимо выделение памяти именно в отдельной процедуре

Tags: c, динамические-массивы, процедуры

Выделение памяти в процедуре под двумерный массив

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
        
// Объявление процедуры выделения памяти
void memoryAllocation( int ***arr, int *column, int *line);
        
int main() {
    // Двумерный динамический массив
    int **array = NULL;  

    // Размерность массива
    int column = 7, line = 5;  

    // Процедура выделения памяти
    memoryAllocation( &array, &column, &line);  

    // Освободим память
    free (array); 
    array = NULL;
    return 0;
}
 
// Процедура выделения памяти под динамический двумерный массив       
void memoryAllocation( int ***arr, int *column, int *line) {
     *arr = malloc(*column * sizeof(*arr));
     for (int index = 0; index < *column; index++) {
     *arr[index] = malloc(*line * sizeof(**arr));
     }
}
```

В итоге при попытке поработать с ним, выдается Segmentation fault( При выделение в функции main ошибок нет, а при попытке работы во внешних функциях есть...
Помогите разобраться!

Comment: Этот код просто не компилируется.

Comment: Напутано со скобками. Непонятно, что такое ```array``` в функции....

Comment: Зачем вы 2 последних параметров передаёте через указатель? Вы же не меняете их значения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще надо скобочки ставить. Приоритет у квадратных скобочек больше, чем у разыменования. Надо значения ставить `(*arr)[index] = ..`. Ещё перепутали размеры указателей `sizeof(int*)` *(или `sizeof(**arr)`)* с простыми типами `sizeof(int)` *(или `sizeof(***arr)`)*.

```
// Процедура выделения памяти под динамический двумерный массив       
void memoryAllocation( int ***arr, int *column, int *line) {
     *arr = malloc(*column * sizeof(int*));
     for (int index = 0; index < *column; index++) {
       (*arr)[index] = malloc(*line * sizeof(int));
     }
}
```

Comment: Исправил размеры типов.

Comment: Можете обьяснить в чем разница между "sizeof(*array) и sizeof(*int)"?

Comment: `arr == int***` , `*arr == int**` , `**arr == int*` , `***arr == int`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!